# Difference in items height at layouts with same DP value

Tags: android, layout, pixel, screen-resolution, density-independent-pixel

I am running 2 emulators:

1. 360x640 mdpi (1x)
2. 1080x1920 xxhdpi (3x)

Using dp values when defining attributes for views should result in covering same physical space, but as the result they look different.

What might be the reason for such outcome?

[image: difference in height of buttons]

Comment: Can you post you xml layout please, it may help answer you question.